# change double click to simple click in tree.js code

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

I've not been able to modify the code from [tree.js](https://github.com/lunu-bounir/tree.js/blob/master/tree.js) to allow user to open a folder when clicking on a node (folder name). You can see [the website I'm building here](https://www.dhammacharts.org/quartz/) where the folder named "**notes**" appears at the top left.

For the moment one needs to double click on the folder name or simple click on the arrow to open the folder. I cannot see where double click is called in the code.

I would like to **simple click the folder's name to open it**.

[image]

Thanks ! my code for this site is in [this github branch](https://github.com/DhammaCharts/quartz/tree/new-layout). It is generated with Hugo, but better look at [tree.js](https://github.com/lunu-bounir/tree.js/blob/master/tree.js) for the source that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to modify the code. Just manually open on select event.

```
tree.on('select', e => {
  if (e.tagName === 'SUMMARY') {
    tree.open(e.parentElement);
  }
});
```

from https://github.com/lunu-bounir/tree.js/issues/1